# If not Check then Add to Cash

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is probably simple, atleast I am hoping, but I am having  feats with it.

I have 5 textboxes for entering check amount in StepA.

If what I enter in StepA is check Amount, the same amount entered, goes to StepB.

If what I enter in StepA is cash only, it does not go to StepB. I stays in StepA only.

So far so good because it works.

No box for entering cash. However, we have cash fieldname on the db.

We we would like to do is to find a way to insert the amount entered for Check into check fieldname in the DB and the cash into cash fieldname.

So far, we are inserting '' (empty string) into cash field.

I can't wrap around my head, how to handle this.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Here is the relevant code. As you can see from the code, this -->

```
*chckval = GridView1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x)) represents check.*

For x = 1 To 5 Step 1
    dedval = GridView1.FindControl("ded" & CStr(x))
    chckval = GridView1.FindControl("chck" & CStr(x))
    chcknumval = GridView1.FindControl("chcknum" & CStr(x))
    onetimeval = GridView1.FindControl("onetime" & CStr(x))
    multival = GridView1.FindControl("multi" & CStr(x))
    If dedval.Text <> "-1" And donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value <> "No" Then
        sql += "INSERT INTO EmpTable (employee_id, charity_code, check_amt, chcknum, one_time, bi_weekly, cash, donate_choice, date_stamp) "
        sql += "VALUES ('" & employee_idLabel.Text & "','" & dedval.SelectedValue & "','" & chckval.Text & "','" & chcknumval.Text & "','" & onetimeval.Text & "','" & multival.Text & "','','" & donatechoice.SelectedItem.Value & "','" & datestamp & "');"
    End If
```

I forgot to mention that users are required to enter check# for anybox that has a checkamount. Not sure if that helps.

What I am thinking, as a possible solution, is that since there are 5 checkboxes, and a user must check a box to indicate the amount being paid is for check, I am thinking of constructing something like:

If checkbox.checked and the associated check textbox is not empty, Then ' this is for check, add it to check fieldname
insert....
else ' even though the associated check textbox is not empty, the checkbox isn't checked. Therefore, this must be cash, insert into cash fieldname
end if. I just don't know the correct syntax.

Comment: Are you familiar with parameterized queries? If not, become so. Constructing SQL as you have done can open you up to SQL injection.

Comment: Why is there a c# tag on this post?

Comment: I left the C# tag in there because I wanted to increase my chances of getting a response. Some may prefer to assist with C# which I can then convert to VB. Anthony, thanks for your feedback. I still need help though.

Comment: What is hard about this?  If it is a check, insert the amount into the check field.  Otherwise, insert the amount into the cash field.  Just an IF..THEN statement.

Comment: I don't think you have read my comments carefully. It isn't as easy as it seems to you.

Comment: I don't think you've explained the problem very well.  If there is no data entry field for cash, then where does the cash value come from?  How do you determine if an amount is check or cash?  Or are you possibly talking about GROSS and NET values?

Comment: there 5 textboxes textbox1 through textbox5 to enter check amount into each box in StepA. Then there are 5 checkboxes, checkbox1 through checkbox5. If a user is given some money to record, if the money is check, then check the checkbox first and then enter the money. If it happens as described, the money entered MUST be check and it is automatically inserted into corresponding textbox in StepB. If the amount entered into StepA is NOT a check, then it must be cash. Problem is the way the code was written, you have to figure out a way to record the cash and that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: What I am thinking, as a possible solution, is that since there are 5 checkboxes, and a user must check a box to indicate the amount being paid is for check, I am thinking of constructing something like: If checkbox.checked and the associated textbox is not empty, Then ' this is for check, add it to check fieldname insert.... else ' even though the associated check textbox is not empty, the checkbox isn't checked. Therefore, this must be cash, insert into cash fieldname end if. I just don't know the correct syntax.

Comment: if you can show a screen shot with explanations, it would be great. A ppt kind of thing would be even great. Try google docs, or zoho for that...